# ASM help - assembly language binary bomb phase_6

Tags: assembly

I have been working on this for hours. I have tried to find the right answer, but I just can't. I have searched around, and many people say that the input is numbers 1-6 and no repeat, but I can't find where it says that anywhere in the assembly code. Also, I finally found the nodes after looking hard for them.

```
(gdb)   x /4x 0x804a62c
0x804a62c <node0>:  0x00000006  0x00000000  0x0804a620  0x000003e9

(gdb) x /4x 0x804a614
0x804a614 <node2>:  0x0000003e  0x00000002  0x0804a608  0x0000014b

(gdb) x /4x 0x804a620
0x804a620 <node1>:  0x0000014b  0x00000001  0x0804a62c  0x00000006

(gdb) x /4x 0x804a608
0x804a608 <node3>:  0x000003e4  0x00000003  0x0804a5fc  0x0000003e

(gdb) x /4x 0x804a5fc
0x804a5fc <node4>:  0x0000016e  0x00000004  0x0804a5f0  0x000003e4

(gdb) x /4x 0x804a5f0
0x804a5f0 <node5>:  0x00000397  0x00000005  0x0804a5e4  0x0000016e

(gdb) x /4x 0x804a5e4
0x804a5e4 <node6>:  0x00000194  0x00000006  0x0804a5d8  0x00000397

(gdb) x /4x 0x804a5d8
0x804a5d8 <node7>:  0x000002a8  0x00000007  0x0804a5cc  0x00000194

(gdb) x /4x 0x804a5cc
0x804a5cc <node8>:  0x000000b9  0x00000008  0x0804a5c0  0x000002a8

(gdb) x /4x 0x804a5c0
0x804a5c0 <node9>:  0x00000355  0x00000009  0x00000000  0x000000b9
```

So I put them in order and I got 3 5 9 7 6 4 1 8 2 0 , but when I put that in, it still doesn't work. Here is the asm code for this

```
     Dump of assembler code for function phase_6:
       0x08048ca0 <+0>: push   %ebp
       0x08048ca1 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
       0x08048ca3 <+3>: push   %ebx
       0x08048ca4 <+4>: sub    $0x14,%esp
       0x08048ca7 <+7>: movl   $0xa,0x8(%esp)
       0x08048caf <+15>:    movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
       0x08048cb7 <+23>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
       0x08048cba <+26>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
       0x08048cbd <+29>:    call   0x80487e8 <strtol@plt>
       0x08048cc2 <+34>:    mov    $0x804a62c,%ebx
       0x08048cc7 <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%ebx)
       0x08048cc9 <+41>:    mov    %ebx,(%esp)
       0x08048ccc <+44>:    call   0x8048b8d <fun6>
       0x08048cd1 <+49>:    mov    0x8(%eax),%eax
       0x08048cd4 <+52>:    mov    0x8(%eax),%eax
       0x08048cd7 <+55>:    mov    0x8(%eax),%eax
       0x08048cda <+58>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
       0x08048cdc <+60>:    cmp    (%ebx),%eax
       0x08048cde <+62>:    je     0x8048ce5 <phase_6+69>
       0x08048ce0 <+64>:    call   0x8049236 <explode_bomb>
       0x08048ce5 <+69>:    add    $0x14,%esp
       0x08048ce8 <+72>:    pop    %ebx
       0x08048ce9 <+73>:    pop    %ebp
       0x08048cea <+74>:    ret    
    End of assembler dump.

And for the fun6 function:

Dump of assembler code for function fun6:
   0x08048b8d <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048b8e <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048b90 <+3>: push   %edi
   0x08048b91 <+4>: push   %esi
   0x08048b92 <+5>: push   %ebx
   0x08048b93 <+6>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   0x08048b96 <+9>: mov    0x8(%edx),%esi
   0x08048b99 <+12>:    movl   $0x0,0x8(%edx)
   0x08048ba0 <+19>:    mov    %edx,%eax
   0x08048ba2 <+21>:    mov    %edx,%ecx
   0x08048ba4 <+23>:    mov    %edx,%edi
   0x08048ba6 <+25>:    test   %esi,%esi
   0x08048ba8 <+27>:    jne    0x8048bd8 <fun6+75>
   0x08048baa <+29>:    jmp    0x8048be4 <fun6+87>
   0x08048bac <+31>:    mov    %edx,%ecx
   0x08048bae <+33>:    mov    0x8(%ecx),%edx
   0x08048bb1 <+36>:    test   %edx,%edx
   0x08048bb3 <+38>:    je     0x8048bb9 <fun6+44>
   0x08048bb5 <+40>:    cmp    %ebx,(%edx)
   0x08048bb7 <+42>:    jg     0x8048bac <fun6+31>
   0x08048bb9 <+44>:    mov    %ecx,%edi
   0x08048bbb <+46>:    mov    %edx,%ecx
   0x08048bbd <+48>:    cmp    %ecx,%edi
   0x08048bbf <+50>:    jne    0x8048bc5 <fun6+56>
   0x08048bc1 <+52>:    mov    %esi,%eax
   0x08048bc3 <+54>:    jmp    0x8048bc8 <fun6+59>
   0x08048bc5 <+56>:    mov    %esi,0x8(%edi)
   0x08048bc8 <+59>:    mov    0x8(%esi),%edx
   0x08048bcb <+62>:    mov    %ecx,0x8(%esi)
   0x08048bce <+65>:    test   %edx,%edx
   0x08048bd0 <+67>:    je     0x8048be4 <fun6+87>
   0x08048bd2 <+69>:    mov    %edx,%esi
   0x08048bd4 <+71>:    mov    %eax,%ecx
   0x08048bd6 <+73>:    mov    %eax,%edi
   0x08048bd8 <+75>:    test   %ecx,%ecx
   0x08048bda <+77>:    je     0x8048bbd <fun6+48>
   0x08048bdc <+79>:    mov    (%esi),%ebx
   0x08048bde <+81>:    cmp    %ebx,(%ecx)
   0x08048be0 <+83>:    jg     0x8048bae <fun6+33>
   0x08048be2 <+85>:    jmp    0x8048bbd <fun6+48>
   0x08048be4 <+87>:    pop    %ebx
   0x08048be5 <+88>:    pop    %esi
   0x08048be6 <+89>:    pop    %edi
   0x08048be7 <+90>:    pop    %ebp
   0x08048be8 <+91>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I have been at this for hours! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you put your question more concrete?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? because, I really think that 3 5 9 7 6 4 1 8 2 0 is the correct answer, but the program doesn't see it that way.

Comment: I am. I am using gdb and I have tried using ddd.

Comment: ddd is just a frontend to gdb.

Comment: @user2396030
What do you expect, how did you run this etc etc.
I'd use Olly to single-step it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are many versions of the bomb, so the fact that some people told you the answer was `3 5 9 7 6 4 1 8 2 0` doesn't have much to do with the facts. As you can see, `phase6` invokes a single `strtol` on line `+29`, so only a single number is expected as input. That number is then stored into `node0` and `fun6` is invoked with the node's address, which will eventually return with a node pointer that is checked for some condition. Try to work out what `fun6` is doing and what the condition is.

Comment: No one told me the answer was 3 5 9 7 6 4 1 8 2 0, in fun6 it is just making a linked list. So then you just have to order the other part of each node, and when you put it in order, I get 3 5 9 7 6 4 1 8 2 0